# example code of dialog box does nothing

Tags: google-apps-script

**I opened a new question: [example code of dialog box makes a mess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184071/example-code-of-dialog-box-makes-a-mess)**

I am trying to run the example in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/dialog-box

```
function doGet() {
    var app = UiApp.createApplication();
    // Create a dialog box.
    var dialog = app.createDialogBox();
    // Add a label to the dialog and set the dimensions and position.
    dialog.setPopupPosition(100, 100).setSize(500, 500).show();
    // Show the dialog. Note that it does not have to be "added" to the UiInstance.
    dialog.show();
    return app;
}
```

and nothing happens. what am I missing?

**EDIT:**

I didn't know about the need for deploying as webapp, but now I have another problem
after running the code above as webapp I get:
[image: that whats happens]

What am I missing this time?

Comment: This widget seems to be a bit buggy... try another one :-) and eventually raise an issue on the issue tracker.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the documentation about [deploying a webapp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps#deploying), this applies to all types of webapps that work as standalone applications.
To run this example you'll need to save a version and to deploy it to get its working url.(and also a special 'dev' url to test the latest version of your code.[image]

here is the url to this demo where I added a few details : [link](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbykgql3pnLnEuM3ylm9QSv1hyUK2yxfz39wJq7VgxFHPRAg30Gz/exec)

here is the demo code :

```
function doGet() {
    var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('dialogBoxTest');
    var abs = app.createAbsolutePanel().setWidth('100%').setHeight('100%');
    abs.add(app.createLabel('demo test').setStyleAttributes({'fontSize':'25pt','padding':'30px'}));
    app.add(abs);
    // Create a dialog box.
    var dialog = app.createDialogBox(true,true).setHTML('DialogBox').setAnimationEnabled(true);
    // Add a label to the dialog and set the dimensions and position.
    dialog.add(app.createLabel('hello world'));
    dialog.setPopupPosition(100, 100).setSize(100, 100);// no need to call show() twice as in the example ...
    // Show the dialog. Note that it does not have to be "added" to the UiInstance.
    dialog.show();
    return app;
}
```

That said (and strictly in my opinion) this widget is quite ugly... ;-) popups can have a far better look with some styleAttributes.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing nothing. Your code example as you stated is directly a copy from the online documentation provided by Google for Google Apps Script.

As suggested by Serge insas an issue was created in fact 2 were numbers 2917 and 2097 which has been accept and official resolution is still in works. Though it was stated that the dialog box created by the CreateDialogBox method has rendering problems when setting the size. See this comment:

https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2907#c1

So you could create an element inside the dialog box to force the dialog to a specific size:

Code Example:

```
function DialogBoxPopUp(){

  // Gets the active UiInstance.
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var dialog = app.createDialogBox();

  dialog.setPopupPosition(150, 150)
  //.setSize(500, 500)
  //instead create an element inside the DialogBox that is the desired size.
  .setHTML('<div id="container" style="width:500px;height:500px">This is just one example</div>')
  .show();

  return app;
}
```

Though this may present other unseen/unknown problems so check your work. The PopupPanel could be an option as well and the documented example works.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/popup-panel

Here is another simple example providing an easy way to provide some style automatically using a caption panel.

```
function MakePopupPanel(){

  // Gets the active UiInstance.
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var popUp = app.createPopupPanel();

  popUp.add(app.createCaptionPanel("caption panel in a popup"))
  .setWidth("100px").setHeight("100px")
  .setPopupPosition(100, 100);

  popUp.show();

  return app;
}
```