# example code of dialog box makes a mess

Tags: google-apps-script

I did:

```
function doGet() {
var app = UiApp.createApplication();
// Create a dialog box.
var dialog = app.createDialogBox();
// Add a label to the dialog and set the dimensions and position.
dialog.setPopupPosition(100, 100).setSize(500, 500).show();
// Show the dialog. Note that it does not have to be "added" to the UiInstance.
dialog.show();
return app;
}
```

Deployed and got:
[image]

This is obviously not what I expected. 
what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, `.createDialogBox()` seems to be broken. Write your entry into the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) I'll star it as soon as your entry shows up there.

I use `PopupPanel` which works fine and gives the same functionality minus the draggability

Comment: [Issue 2907](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2907) has been entered.

Comment: Possible work-around in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14432143/1677912).

Comment: I saw Mogsdad comment to late. I entered another Issue (2917)

Comment: A response was added to Issue 2907 - the work-around is to use only the default size - remove any calls to `.setSize()` or `.setPixelSize()`. That makes the popup usable, but is still a bug.